# nomencl: Rearrange order of Description and Unit

Tags: nomencl

So I have my nomenclature almost the way I want it. The only thing I can not find out how to do is change the order of Description and Unit.

The Way I have it now is: Label / Description / Unit.

But I want it to appear like this: Label / Unit / Description.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[intoc,german]{nomencl} 
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
    {\leftmargin\labelwidth}
    {\leftmargin\labelwidth\itemindent 1em }
    {}{}
\newcommand{\nomenclheader}[1]{%
    \item[\hspace*{-\itemindent}\bfseries#1]{\ }\vspace{\baselineskip}}
    \renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
        \itemsep\baselineskip%
            \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
            {A}{\nomenclheader{Lateinische Symbole}}%   
            {B}{\nomenclheader{Griechische Symbole}}%   
            {C}{\nomenclheader{Subskripte}}%        
            {D}{\nomenclheader{Abkürzungen}}%
            }%
        \itemsep\nomitemsep% restore spacing
        }
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}\makebox[3cm]{$\left[ #1 \right]$\hfill}}\ignorespaces}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\baselineskip} 
\makenomenclature   

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature[3cm] 


this is a test
\nomenclature[A]{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame\nomunit{m/s}}
\nomenclature[A]{$a$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame\nomunit{km/s}}
\nomenclature[B]{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature[C]{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature[D]{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks:

[image: Example]